# How can I change the zoom level of a page from code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Is it possible to change the zoom level using the code behind file (.cs) for an aspx page when I click on a button?

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkZoom"  OnClick="lnkZoom_onClick"  Text="Zoom" Font-Italic="true" Font-Size="XX-Small"></asp:LinkButton>  



protected void lnkZoom_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "zoom()", true);

       // c# code to do the same as above instead of firing the js function.
    }
```

I tried with JS but when I click on it, its doesn't work.. so I am trying to do the same some other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most websites use the font-size to implement zoom. If EVERYTHING zoomed it would throw off the entire layout.

Most zoom features do something like this...

```js
var zoomLevel = 100;
function zoomIn(){
    zoomLevel += 10;
 document.body.style.fontSize = zoomLevel+"%";
}

function zoomOut(){
    zoomLevel -= 10;
 document.body.style.fontSize = zoomLevel+"%";
}
```

```css
button{font-size: 90%;}
```

```html
<button onclick='zoomIn()'>zoom In</button>
<button onclick='zoomOut()'>zoom Out</button>
<h1>
scenester unicorn four loko
</h1>
<p>
Butcher street art VHS disrupt, craft beer pug microdosing 8-bit viral health goth chartreuse squid. Tote bag farm-to-table raw denim celiac, vinyl shoreditch hammock normcore tilde pok pok skateboard 90's jean shorts. Cray humblebrag put a bird on it organic ennui. Franzen bicycle rights tbh art party mlkshk. Celiac live-edge truffaut YOLO before they sold out 90's. Authentic umami everyday carry gluten-free listicle lyft. Flexitarian four dollar toast stumptown shabby chic bicycle rights.
</p>
```

This way everything stays relative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the script tags.

Instead of

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "zoom()", true);
```

try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", @"<SCRIPT type=""text/javascript"">zoom();</SCRIPT>", true);
```

or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", @"<SCRIPT type=""text/javascript"">document.body.style.zoom = ""300%"";</SCRIPT>", true);
```